# Ignoring Auto-Generated AWS Amplify Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using CircleCI as CI/CD for an Angular application built with AWS Amplify. For this application, which auto-generated Amplify files do I need to add to my `.gitignore`? I am concerned about security.

Answer (score 1):

`amplify init` generates metadata files to configure the Amplify environment.
You can find a summary of some of the metadata - generated folders and files as well as whether they can be edited and whether they need to be placed under source control - under https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/files

The `.gitignore` file of your project is typically updated automatically by amplify to take into account these 'rules'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my .gitignore looks like, hope it helps.

```
node_modules/
dist/
release/

#amplify
amplify/\#current-cloud-backend
amplify/.config/local-*
amplify/mock-data
amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json
amplify/backend/awscloudformation
build/
dist/
node_modules/
aws-exports.js
awsconfiguration.json
amplifyconfiguration.json
amplify-build-config.json
amplify-gradle-config.json
amplifytools.xcconfig
```